# Returning a Comparable from an Interface Method

Tags: java, interface, comparable

In Java, one can allow an interface-specified function to return a `Comparable` simply by using a return type of `Comparable`. This isn't particularly useful, however, since there's no guarantee that two different implementations of this interface will return `Comparable`s that can be compared to each other. Is there some way of doing this?

To illustrate my question, let's say we're making a class that stores objects and automatically 1) groups them and 2) sorts these groups. So something like:

GroupList.java

```
public class GroupList<T extends Groupable> {
  private HashMap<Comparable, T[]> data;
  public void add(T e) {
    Comparable group = e.getGroup();
    if(!data.containsKey(group)) { /* make new group for the element */ }
    /* add element to matching group */
  }
  public T[][] get() {
    /* return all the data, with the sets ordered by their Comparable */
  }
}
```

Groupable.java

```
public interface Groupable {
  public Comparable getGroup();
}
```

This runs into the aforementioned problem, however, which means that things like this are possible:

```
Class A implements Groupable {
  String datestamp;
  public Comparable getGroup() { return datestamp; }
}
Class B implements Groupable {
  Date datestamp;
  public Comparable getGroup() { return datestamp; }
}
```

This is further complicated by the fact that while all the `Comparable`s must work with each other, I do not know ahead of time what they will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the Comparable subclass a generic parameter, too.

Something like

```
public interface Groupable<G extends Comparable<G>> {
  public G getGroup();
}

public class GroupList<G extends Comparable<G>> {
  private HashMap<G, Groupable<G>[]> data;
  public void add(Groupable<G> e) {
    G group = e.getGroup();
    if(!data.containsKey(group)) { /* make new group for the element */ }
    /* add element to matching group */
  }
  public Groupable<G>[][] get() {
    /* return all the data, with the sets ordered by their Comparable */
  }
}
```

In this case, if you have `class A implements Groupable<String>`, and `class B implements Groupable<Date>`, you can't mix them in the same GroupList, but you can still mix a different class with the same grouping class, e.g. `class C implements Groupable<String>`

```
GroupList<String> groupList = new GroupList<String>();
groupList.add(new A()); //ok
groupList.add(new B()); //compile error
groupList.add(new C()); //ok
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how this solves the problem - how does moving the declaration of Comparable from GroupList to Groupable force all the Groupables to have Comparables that work together? EDIT: So where would attempting to do as your edit says cause a problem?

Comment: The GroupList now forces to use one Group class for all Groupables to use. So you need to choose in your subclasses which group to use, e.g. `class A implements Groupable<String>`, and `class B implements Groupable<Date>`, so you can't mix them in the same GroupList. In fact, you don't need the T parameter anymore. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. That's slightly inconvenient, since that means you have to repeat yourself between the implementation of `Groupable` and then every time you use that implementation in a `GroupList`, but I don't really see any other way to do it. I couldn't handle that at runtime by asking the `Groupable` for its `Comparable`'s class, could I?

Comment: I mean, is it possible to use that to replace the `String` parameter to `GroupList`? Not to guard against bad types as such, but to reduce the length of the declaration and reduce the amount the programmer has to know about the `Groupable`.

Comment: No, the java compiler can't use runtime information (i.e. reflection) at compile time :-(

Comment: Ah, well. Thought I'd might as well ask. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @Invictus - my impression is that you want to group by String.class, Date.class etc. This info can be available by reflection. e.g. given any Object, you can check whether it has a super interface `Comparable<X>`, and what `X` is.

Comment: Sorry if my post gave you that impression, @bayou.io - that is not what I am looking for. For another example, consider a `CalendarItem` class that is `Groupable` and returns a `Date` field as its `Comparable`. A `GroupList` object containing a bunch of `CalendarItem`s would be able to sort those `CalendarItem`s by their dates. What I wanted to guard against was then trying to add a `StringCalendarItem` that returns a `String` as its `Comparable`.